# Bibliographic references in a bulleted/numbered list

Tags: bibliographies, lists

Let's say there are 3 bibliographic references I want to cite, but I want them to appear inmediatelly and in a bullet list, how can I do it? And in a numbered list?

Comment: How are you managing your bibliography? `natbib`? `biblatex`?

Comment: I am using bibtex, sorry

Comment: OK, I got it, just using \usepackage{biblatex} and \fullcite{...} inside \begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{bla 06a} ...

Comment: What `bibliographystyle` are you using?

Comment: Yes with biblatex it is easy. It's best to research questions before asking them here.

Comment: the default one

Comment: just the last comment, in this case, how can I do so that all authors appear in the citation and it is not shortened?

Comment: Look at page 44 of the [biblatex manual](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: ok, so maxnames = 10, etc

Comment: can you switch your comment to answer so that I give you the points?+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BibLaTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) offers the `\fullcite` option which prints the whole reference. What counts as the "whole reference" depends on the `bibstyle` option. You could then just do:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{book1}
\item \fullcite{paper7}
\end{itemize}
```

I believe [Jurabib](http://ctan.org/pkg/jurabib) offers some similar functionality if you wanted to stick with bibtex...