# Cite bibliography in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am preparing a beamer presentation. In some slides (4 of 30) I want to cite one or two bibliographic references and put them at the bottom of each slide. They lie there just as a bulleted list, not being cited in the text of the slide.

I wonder what is the best approach to do so.

PS: I forgot to mention that bibliographic entries are stored in a .bib file

Comment: From your [previous](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21697/510) question, you know how to create references as "bulleted lists" using biblatex. Have you tried the beamer/biblatex combo?

Comment: yes, I have tried this, sorry. The problem now is that I do not get the same format for bibliography in both latex document and beamer presentation; in beamer it gets a bit weird; I do not like ; authors, ... IN Journal ...

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/510.

Comment: ok, but now the problem continues; I get "pp" for the page numbers, like if I was to cite a proceeding instead of a journal, and the volume number appers weird like 13.4 instead of 13(4) ... can not tell beamer to put them in some concrete style?

Comment: beamer has nothing to do with bibliography styles. For customizing biblatex styles, have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) question (e.g. it tells you how to remove "pp."). Anyhow, you should ask a new question if you need additional advice.

Comment: I had a look at the question you mention. You did a very good work. The thing as I see it now is; I have to prepare a talk for a lecture, have 3 hours left. In Latex I have no problem with citations and bibliography, but in beamer it seems so hard (like this case now, having to add the ":in remover" and now the "pp remover) that I just prefer to forget about it and directly paste the references from a PDF from Latex of the paper I have. Sorry, I know that it is a cheap approach but life is short and I have more urgent things to do (finish my lecture). At least I tried. Thanks for your help

Comment: I see ... Good luck with your talk, and consider to switch to biblatex for your next document!

Comment: thanks. You mean using biblatex for a beamer document in the terms I mentioned (citations appear on some slides only, and in Journal style, not proceeding)? Could you point me to some link?

Comment: One advantage of biblatex is that you can display citations without also typesetting the bibliography (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10547/can-i-use-natbib-in-beamer-but-omit-the-bibliography)). I don't know what "Journal style" means.

Comment: I put a new example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26959/cite-bibliography-in-beamer-with-a-concrete-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here a minimal example, which you should provide.:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={A book},
publisher={Puplisher},
year={1742},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
asd\cite{test}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

ALSO NO PROBLEM -- but the same problem you have to provide a minimal example.

Comment: thanks a lot, I forgot to mention that bibliographic entries are stored in a .bib file

Comment: @flow: Same as usual.

Comment: thanks, now it works. The problem now is that I do not get the same format for bibliography in both latex document and beamer presentation; in beamer it gets a bit weird; I do not like ; authors, ... IN Journal ... –

Comment: so I wonder how can I give it the exact format for the biliography, I just would like; authors, title, journal, etc (similar so American Medical Association style)

Comment: Ok, I reformulated my question and put an example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26959/cite-bibliography-in-beamer-with-a-concrete-style