# Cite bibliography in beamer with a concrete style

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

In a beamer presentation I want to cite some bibliography. I prepared the following minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}



@article{ZINC,
author = {Irwin, John J and Shoichet, Brian K},
title = {{ZINC--a free database of commercially available compounds for virtual screening.}},
journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling},
year = {2005},
volume = {45},
number = {1},
pages = {177--182},
}



@article{Jorgensen,
author = {Jorgensen, WL},
title = {{The many roles of computation in drug discovery}},
journal = {Science},
year = {2004},
volume = {303},
number = {5665},
pages = {1813--1818},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
This is a nice paper \cite{ZINC,Jorgensen}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get at the end of the presentation a slide with both citations, in the exact style I need them (sorry if "style" is not the exact word here). But I do not want this, I want, on the slide I cite them, them to appear with this format, and omit the final slide with all the bibliography. How can this be done? I hope my question is more clear now

PS: The format I want is

John J Irwin and Brian K Shoichet.
ZINC–a free database of commercially available compounds for virtual screening. Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling, 45(1):177–182, 2005.

with the title of the journal in italics (Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling in this case) in italics

Comment: What is the citation style of the American Medical Society?

Comment: Your message is quite uninformative, like the linked one. I didn't downvote, but I wouldn't upvote either. Please, try and improve your message with an example frame, a couple of bibliography items and a pointer to the Am. Med. Soc. format.

Comment: Ok, I will do it

Comment: That is not a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also, you haven't described the format you want them to appear in.

Comment: I did it, I hope it is more clear now

Comment: @flow: I prefer `biblatex` I think to redefine the `bst-file` is to much.

Comment: well, how would you then modify it to add biblatex? can you post is as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
%   \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% NEW
  \iffieldundef{series}{%
  }{%
    \newunit
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
  }%
  \printfield{volume}%
%   \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{note}% NEW
  \setunit{\addcolon}% NEW
  \printfield{pages}% NEW
  \setunit{\addspace}% NEW
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ZINC,
author = {Irwin, John J and Shoichet, Brian K},
title = {ZINC--a free database of commercially available compounds for virtual screening},
journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling},
year = {2005},
volume = {45},
number = {1},
pages = {177--182},
}
@article{Jorgensen,
author = {Jorgensen, WL},
title = {The many roles of computation in drug discovery},
journal = {Science},
year = {2004},
volume = {303},
number = {5665},
pages = {1813--1818},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
This is a nice paper: \textcite{ZINC,Jorgensen}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great! It works but I think it is something really complicated, not everybody can do that. Imagine every morning you prepare your coffee or tee or whatever, you had to write down the molecular formulae of the implicated compounds in order to get a good roast, would not it be a bit tiring?

Comment: My theory is that later versions of biblatex will be just as easy to use as the current version is powerful. For now, enjoy your coffee. ;-)